# MySQL database not starting in XAMPP Ubuntu 18.04 with "/opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process" error

Tags: php, session, phpmyadmin, xampp

I installed XAMPP on ubuntu 18.04. But when I visit `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/` then I get this error.

[image]

And when I am trying to start MySQL database only it not start.

[image]

Also on command, I try to start XAMPP I got this error.

> /opt/lampp/bin/mysql.server: 264: kill: No such process

Answer (score 1):

There is a `Permission denied` error.

Try to stop the service as sudo:

`sudo service mysql stop`

and start it again:

`run sudo /opt/lampp/xampp start`

I had a similar problem.

If it still doesn't work try changing the permissions:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 /opt/lampp
sudo chown -hR nobody /opt/lampp
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/lampp
```

And then restart it with the previous commands.

Comment: Still, MySQL is not running.

Comment: It shows you any error while executing the start command? Is it the same error or another one?

Comment: Try another thing. Just stop the mysql service `sudo service mysql stop` and start xampp. Maybe the error you get is because the mysql is running and xampp tries to start it again at the same port & same config.